# Load all tables of certain class on successful ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

My requirement is to load all `tables` with certain `class` attribute in their respective `div` on successful ajax call. Currently loading a single `table` in single `div` is working fine using following statement.

```
$('#div1').load(' #table1');
```

But I want load all the tables in respective div. Following is my  sample html code

```
<div id="div1" class="div">
    <table id="table1" class="table"></table>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="div">
    <table id="table2" class="table"></table>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="div">
    <table id="table3" class="table"></table>
</div>
```

I tried to do

```
 $('.div').load(' .table');
```

But it loads all `tables` in each `div`. How can I achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

NOTE : I have not posted original code as it  was distracting. All tables are loading data from mysql database using JSP.

Comment: What are you expecting `load('#table1')` to do?

Comment: I am expecting it to load Row details from a mysql table using JSP

Comment: read the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Can you explain your code `load('#table1')` ?

Comment: @waLLe the OP added a note to the question about it - that's just simplified logic as it's not relevant to the question. The actual production code works as it uses `load()` correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can DRY this up by using the common classes on the parent `div` and child `table` elements to loop and call `load()` with the relevant URL and `id`:

```html
<div class="div">
    <table id="table1" class="table"></table>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <table id="table2" class="table"></table>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <table id="table3" class="table"></table>
</div>
```

```js
$('.div').each(function() {
  var $table = $(this).find('.table');
  $table.load(`${url} #${$table.prop('id')}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (x=1; x < document.getElementsByClassName('div').length; x++) {
    $('#div' + x).load('#table' + x);
}
```

Assuming each table corresponds to thr same numbered div.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with a one liner like

```js
$(".table").append("<tr><td>load data</td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
    <table id="table1" class="table"></table>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <table id="table2" class="table"></table>
</div>
<div class="div">
    <table id="table3" class="table"></table>
</div>
```